# Batch file that copies files containing certain keywords from a list to a new directory

Tags: list, batch-file

I currently have a huge dataset at work from which I want to extract all files that contain certain keywords/keynumbers.

Here is an example:

My folder contains:

order1_item3567.pdf

order3_item892.pdf

892_order5.pdf

etc.

I now want to grab all files containing "892" and copy them to a new folder.
I have a text file called items.txt that now contains "892" and around 300 more item Ids. If possible, I would like to have a batch file that reads items.txt and copies all files containing one of the keywords/keynumbers to a new folder.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
if exist "ListFile.txt" (
    if not exist "C:\Temp\NewFolder" md "C:\Temp\NewFolder"
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("ListFile.txt") do (
        copy /Y "*%%I*" "C:\Temp\NewFolder"
    )
)
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`

Comment: Wouldn't you put the `if not exist...` part on the outside of the first `if` statement?

Comment: @EthanMoore does it make sense, to create the directory, when the listfile.txt doesn't exist and no copy will occure?